React-Native Location Tracking
How can I enable continuous location tracking when my React Native app is running in the background?
I’ve tried using expo-location, Expo TaskManager, and react-native-location, but none of them have worked for continuous location tracking in the background.

What didn't work when you tried expo-location? It has background services so when well implemented it should track your location. Here is the link to the section in docs https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/location/#background-location-methods
Remember about proper configuration and permissions
